# Why use a pointer to a pointer in this 'handmade list'?

Tags: c++, pointers

We have a project in school, which, despite what the project is about, it involves the use of linked lists with this specific structure:

```
typedef struct _node {
    int contents;
    _node *next_node;
} *node;
```

Before the project, we were assigned a bunch of functions to learn to work with the list (push a node to the front or back of the list, count the amount of nodes, search for a specific node, etc).

It wasn't all that difficult, but when the teacher sent the base project (so that every one of us started in the same place), all of the functions involve passing a `*node` **by reference**. For example:

```
resultType functionName(node *list, ...) { ... }
```

I did all of the list functions previous to the project with **void** functions, because, as I understand at least, we are working with pointers, so, as long as you don't lose the memory address of the list header, you won't lose the content (and the rest of the list).

So... what is the point of passing a pointer to a pointer in this case? Is there something I'm missing? I asked my teacher and he didn't know how to explain (either that, or he is just as lost as me). I mean, the structure is already a pointer, so, why pass the address of the address of the list?

Comment: Are you sure return type of the function is `resultType` and not `void`?

Comment: This can't be C, because of the `_node` without `struct`.

Comment: You only show a pointer argument. Passing a pointer by reference in C++ (which is _not_ C) would look like `functionName(node *&list, ...)`

Comment: And you don't show a pointer-to-pointer at all (which would be `node **`), so I'm not entirely sure what the question is

Comment: @Useless; `node` is of type `struct _node *`, so `list `is of type `struct _node **`.

Comment: @nwp; He is talking about `_node *next_node;`.

Comment: ew, I always forget to look for that, because it's such an awful idea in the first place.

Comment: Names starting with underscores are reserved for the implementation at file-scope. And **never ever* `typedef` a pointer! And a pointer is **not** a reference! As you use C++, not C, use a reference if you want one.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what is done in the function `functionName`. If you want to allocate onto the `node*` pointer, or you if want to change its value beyond the scope of `functionName`, you need to be able to modify it, and the pointer to the pointer needs to be passed into the function.

To illustrate this with an example, compare the two functions below. The first, `allocate1` is able to do the heap allocation onto the pointer a, because it received the pointer to the pointer. The second, `allocate2` receives the pointer by value, is able to allocate the array, but after returning, the allocated space is lost. This can be seen by comparing the pointer values in the print statement.

```
#include <iostream>

void allocate1(double** a, const int n)
{
    *a = new double[n];
    std::cout << "allocate1: " << *a << std::endl;
}

void allocate2(double* a, const int n)
{
    a = new double[n];
    std::cout << "allocate2: " << a << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    double* test1 = nullptr;
    double* test2 = nullptr;
    int n = 10;

    allocate1(&test1, 10);
    std::cout << "after allocate1: " << test1 << std::endl;
    test1[3] = 16; // OK!

    allocate2(test2, 10);
    std::cout << "after allocate2: " << test2 << std::endl;
    test2[3] = 16; // NOT OK!

    return 0;
}
```

The output on my machine is:

```
allocate1: 0x7fcdd2403160
after allocate1: 0x7fcdd2403160
allocate2: 0x7fcdd24031b0
after allocate2: 0x0
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: Because it's convenient. It allows the function to manipulate the pointer, *irrespective of where it is stored*.

The point is, with a linked list, you want to store a pointer to the first node somewhere. That pointer is not part of a `struct _node`. But you can pass its address to the function just like the address of any `next_node` pointer within any node that's in the list. That is, you do not need to specially treat the case of an empty list.

Just as an example:

```
void pushFront(node* list, int value) {
    node newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    newNode->contents = value;
    newNode->next_node = *list;
    *list = newNode;
}
```

I can call this function like this:

```
int main() {
    node myList = NULL;
    pushFront(&myList, 42);
    printf("The answer is %d!\n", myList->contents);
}
```

Note, that this code works even when `myList` is initialized to `NULL`! Similar elegant code ensues when you walk a list, inserting or deleting nodes along the way.

---

Aside: I think, it is a bad habit to `typedef` pointer types: It hides the fact, that the thing is a pointer. I would very much prefer the following definitions:

```
typedef struct node node;    //avoid having to write `struct` everywhere
struct node {
    int contents;
    node *next_node;
};

void pushFront(node** list, int value);
```

This would imply changing the function implementations to the following (just three more stars):

```
void pushFront(node** list, int value) {
    node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    newNode->contents = value;
    newNode->next_node = *list;
    *list = newNode;
}

int main() {
    node* myList = NULL;
    pushFront(&myList, 42);
    printf("The answer is %d!\n", myList->contents);
}
```

You see, whenever I see a line like

```
node newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
```

I immediately have a WTF moment: "Why is `newNode` treated as a pointer when it's just... oh wait, it's really a pointer type! Someone should really clean up this code!" On the other hand, when I see

```
node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
```

all is immediately clear: `newNode` is a pointer, it's being allocated with `malloc()` in the standard way.

The point is, that I don't expect a pointer unless I see a `*` in the type. Typedefing pointer types breaks this assumption, leading to poorer readability of the code. Especially C programmers like their code explicit in places like these.

Of course, you should stick with the guidelines that your teacher gives you, but make sure to drop the pointer-typedef-habit as soon as you can.

Comment: Good answer, but, still: when you put `node*` (a pointer to a `node` struct) as a type for the parameter `list` in the `pushFront` function, as I understand it (which could be wrong, obviously), that would only work correctly if you define the `node` struct **NOT** as a pointer, am I correct? (When I say _defining the struct as a pointer_, I mean something like `typedef struct node { ... } node*;`. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @S.Díaz My code works exactly as I've written it. I've edited the answer to include the changed code along with the changed declarations now, I hope that helps to clarify things. Note that when `node` is not typedef'ed as a pointer type, the argument to `pushFront()` needs to be declared as `node**`, making it explicit that a double pointer is expected. Consequently, `main()` takes the address of a pointer (`&myList`, where `myList` is defined as `node*`) to pass it as the first argument. I hope this helps. I didn't fully understand your comment, so I might have missed your point :-(

Answer (score 1):

The thing passed into such function is usually the "head", the pointer to the first element of the list.

That head pointer often needs to be modified: when you insert a first node into empty list (the head pointer is changed from NULL to a pointer to the actual node) or when you remove the first element from the list (the head pointer needs to be changed to point to the next list element).

That is why we need to pass a pointer to head rather than head itself.

A better solution would be to have a `List` struct

```
typedef struct _List {
    Node head;
} List;
```

Then you'd pass around a pointer to `List` which makes sense: in C you pass a pointer to something you need to modify.

Comment: I understand what you say about the head and stuff, because we do that, but `*node` is still a pointer struct, so the list is a pointer to the `_node` structure. Why pass the list as reference as `*list` when it is already a pointer?

Comment: You really need to get your teacher to explain this - I doubt you're the only one with this confusion. In the meantime, a hint: Initially, when the list is empty, the head pointer is NULL. If you just pass the pointer, how do you make the list non-empty? IOW, try writing addNode(`_Node *`) and you will see why you need `addNode(_Node **)`

Comment: Sorry for taking time to answer... The work, and studies and stuff...

When we create the list, we do not use a pointer to the first node, which I, personally, don't totally agree to. We actually create a `_node`, and we call that node `header`. It points to a `_node`structure with _empty_ contents (I know it's not actually empty). So, to access the first node, we must start at header, and use `next_node` to reach the first node of the list. When I need to pass the starting node of the list I pass `header->next_node` as an argument.

I hope this clarifies something... Thanks!

Comment: By the way, sorry, I'll post some example code. We create a node like this, using the `new` keyword: `node newNode = new _node`. That allocates space for the node. Then, an example of the `push_front` function: `void push_front(node header, node new_node) { new_node->next_node = header->next_node; header->next_node = new_node; }`.

I'll try as you say, I suppose...

Comment: The code in your comment inserts the new node AFTER the first node. The new node becomes second, not first.

Comment: Yes, I know, because the header is the first node in the way we're doing things, as I said above. Here, the header is _technically_ a node, but we do not use it as such. Say, if a list has 10 items, then, in this model, it actually has 11 nodes (with the header being the first). I think there are better ways to do this, but I must do as my teacher says...

Comment: Aha! In that case, your `header` is my `List`, and you don't need to pass a double pointer. You probably should have mentioned it in the question. Oh, and using _Node where _List is really needed can create all sort of maintainability and clarity issues

Comment: Sorry about that. You're right. To me, use a node as header is wasting memory space (even if we talk about a simple `int`) and kind of confusing, but well... Then again, that's the conclusion? Haha. It makes sense, in this model, to pass the header as `&header`, when it is already a pointer to the `_node` struct? Isn't it adding an unnecesary level of indirection? When I pass the list my way, if I want to access the node's contents, I just do: `current_node->contents`. But, by passing the list as `&list`, won't I have to do it like this: `(*current_node)->contents`?